# Handling Cascading Deletion: Are there ways to do this automatically in mySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I work with an OO database abstraction layer that I wrote.  I have parameters you can set for cleaning up child records when the parent is deleted.

I was wondering if there are other, better ways to do this?  Can you do this in mySQL via a stored procedure or other method?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Could you explain why cascade delete doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Hi Mark,  are you saying mySQL has a native cascade deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what foreign keys can do for you but in MySQL you have to use the [innoDB engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and you have to be sure nobody will ever turn off the foreign key check.